# Drag and Drop, cloneable and removeable

Tags: jquery-ui

I've just started some days ago working with JQuery UI to allow some drag and drop and sorting on my homepage. In the code shown below, i wanted to add "+" and "-" to correct the equation "1_2_3=6", so the "+" has to been dropped two times to make the equation correct.

At the moment, it nearly works perfect. I can add as many "+" and "-" as I want, I can sort them into the equation. The only problem is, that I cannot remove any "+" or "-".

Can you give me any hint, how to be able to remove the signs by moving them out of the sortable window?

Thanks for your help!

```
<html>
<head>

  <style>


  #draggable { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
  #draggable li { display: inline-block; margin: 1%; padding: 1%; font-size: 10vw; text-align:center; min-width:20px; border-style: solid; border-width: medium; border-color:black; background-color:grey;}

  #sortable { float:left; list-style-type: none; width:100%; }
  #sortable li { display: inline-block; margin: 0; padding: 0; font-size: 10vw; text-align:center; min-width:20px;}


  </style>
  <script src="jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {

    $( ".clone").draggable({
        cursor:"move",
        revert: "invalid",
        connectToSortable: '#sortable',
        helper: 'clone'
    });

    $( "#sortable").sortable({
      connectWith: "ul",
      cancel: ".ui-state-disabled",
    });


  } );
  </script>
</head>
<body>


<ul id="draggable">
  <li class="clone">+</li>
  <li class="clone">-</li>
</ul>


<ul id="sortable">
  <li class="ui-state-disabled">1</li>
  <li class="ui-state-disabled">2</li>
  <li class="ui-state-disabled">3=6</li>
</ul>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please consider the following Demo: http://jqueryui.com/droppable/#photo-manager It makes use of a drop-area for "trash", when you want to delete something, you drag it to the trash. You can do the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a div when the UI components are dropped into the div you can remove the dropped component.

Sample code.

```
//HTML

<div class="removeDiv">
  <p>Drop to remove</p>
</div>

//Style
.removeDiv{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:red;
    margin-top:150px;
  }

//Script
$('.removeDiv').droppable({
    over: function(event, ui) {
        ui.draggable.remove();
    }
});
```

This should get your work done.
Here's a fiddle for the above code. [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cnarumanchi/bwrs07qz/)

Comment: Thanks a lot. But is there also a way how to do it without extra "trash" div, so that it will be deleted when it is put back to the other signs or somewhere else on the display?

Comment: Yes, you can do it. My intention was to show you something that works.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on my comment. Your code may look something like this.

```js
$(function() {
  $(".clone").draggable({
    cursor: "move",
    revert: "invalid",
    connectToSortable: '#sortable',
    helper: 'clone'
  });
  $("#sortable").sortable({
    connectWith: "ul",
    cancel: ".ui-state-disabled",
  });
  $(".trash").droppable({
    accept: "#sortable > li",
    classes: {
      "ui-droppable-hover": "ui-state-highlight"
    },
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      deleteItem(ui.draggable);
    }
  });

  function deleteItem($o) {
    $o.fadeOut().remove();
  }
});
```

```css
#draggable {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#draggable li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 1%;
  padding: 1%;
  font-size: 10vw;
  text-align: center;
  min-width: 20px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: medium;
  border-color: black;
  background-color: grey;
}

#sortable {
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 100%;
}

#sortable li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 10vw;
  text-align: center;
  min-width: 20px;
}

.trash {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-radius: 6px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class="drag-items" style="display: block;">
  <ul id="draggable">
    <li class="clone">+</li>
    <li class="clone">-</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="problem" style="display: block;">
  <ul id="sortable">
    <li class="ui-state-disabled">1</li>
    <li class="ui-state-disabled">2</li>
    <li class="ui-state-disabled">3=6</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="trash">
  <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-trash"></span>
</div>
```

In this code, add a small section for items to be dragged to and when they are dropped, they are removed. Also has visual feedback.